# How to solve php Notice: Undefined index

Tags: php

I am working on a php project which is already been developed. Now my work is to change some css files. So to do this I just downloaded all the files from the server along with the database. After all the setup I am getting an error when I am browsing the page is

```
Notice: Undefined index: lang_selected in language.php on line 38
```

and the piece of code which is doing this stuff is

```
if((!isset($_GET['q'])) && ($_SESSION['lang_selected'] == "") && ($ln == 1))
  {

    $language = $setshow['es_lang'];

   if($language=="France")
    $lan="french";

    else if($language=="Croatian")
    $lan="croatian";

    else if($language=="Dutch")
    $lan="dutch";

    else if($language=="German")
    $lan="german";

    else if($language=="Greek")
    $lan="greek";

    else if($language=="Italian")
    $lan="italian";

    else if($language=="Indonesian")
    $lan="indonesian";

    else if($language=="Russia")
    $lan="russian";

    else if($language=="Spain")
    $lan="spanish";

    else if($language=="Usa")
    $lan="english_v1";

    else if($language=="China")
    $lan="chinese";

    else if($language=="Japanese")
    $lan="japanese";

    else if($language=="Korea")
    $lan="korean";

    else if($language=="Saudia")
    $lan="arabic";

    else if($language=="Norwegian")
    $lan="norwegian";

    else if($language=="Malaysian")
    $lan="malaysian";

    else if($language=="Persian")
    $lan="persian";

    else if($language=="Portuguese")
    $lan="portuguese";

    else if($language=="Serbain")
    $lan="serbain";

    else if($language=="Swedish")
    $lan="swedish";

    else if($language=="Thai")
    $lan="thai";

    else if($language=="Vietnamese")
    $lan="vietnamese";

    else if($language=="Turkey")
    $lan="turkish";

    unset($_SESSION['lang']);
   $_SESSION['lang']=$lan;
   $_SESSION['language']=$language;

  }
```

So can some one kindly tell me why this piece of error is coming and how to solve this issue? Any help and suggestions will be appreciable. Thanks

Comment: It seems like $_SESSION['lang_selected'] does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test if an array index exists without triggering a notice use `isset()`.

```
if(isset($array['index'])) doSomething();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should test if `$_SESSION['lang_selected']` exists first.

```
if(!isset($_GET['q']) && (isset($_SESSION['lang_selected']) && $_SESSION['lang_selected'] == "") && ($ln == 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if $_SESSION['lang_selected'] is set using

```
if(isset($_SESSION['lang_selected'])) {
    //do something when lang_selected contains a value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is problem with $_SESSION['lang_selected'] , I think it is not set.

Answer (score -1):

use @$_SESSION['lang_selected'] temporary solution,

Comment: **Hell no**, why do you need to hide warning?